# Get threading.Thread target class object when defined as a variable

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, sockets

I'm trying to understand the basics of networking and I believe the right way to start learning basic server handling is through sockets.

1. I am aware there are better libraries such as twisted or socketServer. I want to do it specifically in socket module.
2. I am aware using socket module to build servers is unreliable.
3. I also am aware I need to implement some kind of protocol for future use.

I tried building P2pClient with threading.Thread inheritance:

```
import socket
import threading


class P2pServer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        print "Info: %s:%s" % (host, port)
        self.server = socket.socket()
        self.server.bind((host, port))
        print "Created the server"
        self.server.listen(1)  # p2p chat

    def run(self):
        while True:
            c, addr = self.server.accept()
            print "Connected from %s (%s)" % (addr, c)


class P2pClient(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, host, port)
        self.client = socket.socket()
        self.client.connect((host, port))

    def send_msg(self, msg):
        try:
            self.client.send(msg)
            return "Sent: %s" % msg
        except socket.error as e:
            return "Could not send because  of %s" % e

    def run(self):
        while True:
            recv = self.client.recv(1024)
            if len(recv) > 0:
                print recv

server = P2pServer("localhost", 44444) # This is our server
server.start() # Run it
client = None

print "Ready to take input"
while True:
    print "Your command: ",
    cmd = raw_input()
    if cmd.startswith("connect "):
        cmd = cmd.split()
        client = P2pClient(cmd[1], cmd[2])
        client.start()
    else:
        client.send_msg(cmd)
```

But ended up getting the following error when the input is "connect localhost :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/edız/Desktop/Ediz/Python/Playground/servers test/p2p.py", line 49, in <module>
    client = P2pClient(cmd[1], cmd[2])
  File "C:/Users/edız/Desktop/Ediz/Python/Playground/servers test/p2p.py", line 22, in __init__
    threading.Thread.__init__(self, host, port)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 670, in __init__
    assert group is None, "group argument must be None for now"
AssertionError: group argument must be None for now
```

Solution on the site suggested making it so that I use the threading.Thread() function directly instead of doing it the former way. However, the threading documenation doesn't give me an idea about how to reach the target function. How can I build the thread that will allow me to access P2pClient in the client variable?

Purpose of the following code is so that it will be run in two different port in same host, making a P2P connection between two servers.

```
import socket
import threading


class P2pServer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        print "Info: %s:%s" % (host, port)
        self.server = socket.socket()
        self.server.bind((host, port))
        print "Created the server"
        self.server.listen(1)  # p2p chat

    def run(self):
        while True:
            c, addr = self.server.accept()
            print "Connected from %s (%s)" % (addr, c)


class P2pClient(object):
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.client = socket.socket()
        self.client.connect((host, int(port)))

    def send_msg(self, msg):
        try:
            self.client.send(msg)
            return "Sent: %s" % msg
        except socket.error as e:
            return "Could not send because  of %s" % e

    def run(self):
        while True:
            recv = self.client.recv(1024)
            if len(recv) > 0:
                print recv

server = P2pServer("localhost", 44444)  # This is our server
server.start()  # Run it
client = None

print "Ready to take input"
while True:
    print "Your command: ",
    cmd = raw_input()
    if cmd.startswith("connect "):
        cmd = cmd.split()
        client = threading.Thread(target=P2pClient, args=(cmd[1], cmd[2]))
        client.start()
    else:
        pass
        # Here I just want something like this:
        # client.send_msg("Hello other server")
```

Comment: Post the full stack trace. We need to know what line in *your* code fails.

Comment: `client = threading.Thread(target=P2pClient, args=(cmd[1], cmd[2]))` isn't going to work. When starting a thread this way, `target` must be a callable (usually a function) that runs the guts of the thread.

Comment: Edited the OP with previous code and the stack trace. I thought the explanation above the trace would've been enough, sorry about that. If the threading.Thread one won't work for what I need to do, how can I adapt the previous code so it satisfies what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first example is close. The problem is that you passed the extra parameters you need for the child `P2pClient` to the parent `Thread` class. `thread` takes a different set of parameters. Just leave those parameters out when initializing the parent.

```
class P2pClient(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.client = socket.socket()
        self.client.connect((host, port))
```

Comment: Works. Thought the parent `Thread` class needs the rest of the args as well when it comes to sockets to be able to maintain a stable connection. Cheers!

Comment: The parent doesn't need the parameters. Perhaps the child needs them to reconnect if the connection fails. In that case, add them to the child's `self` after initializing the parent. the parent is a generic thread that is unaware of what you are implementing.